# PHP - Pagina atualiza sem parar

Tags: php, ajax, apache-cordova

Pessoal quero entender porque acontece isso,

utilizei este código;

```
       <table class="table table-striped  table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Email </th>
                                        <th>Senha</th>
                                      <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                               
                  <?php 


                   include 'database.php';
                   $pdo = Database::connect();
                   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC';
                  

                   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['zname'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['password'] . '</td>';
                          
                            echo '<td width=100%>';
                           
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';

                   }if ($row >= 1){

    $sxURL="tem pedido.php";
  echo ("<script>location.href='$sxURL'</script>");

   }
  else if ($row == 0){

 $fxURL="não tem pedido.php";
  echo ("<script>location.href='$fxURL'</script>");
  
 }else {

   $zxURL="Em análise.php";
  echo ("<script>location.href='$zxURL'</script>");

}
```

Digamos que vai para pagina de condição ( >=1 ) "tem pedido.php" ok, porém fica dando refresh sem parar.

como resolver isso? o que tem de errado este código.

Answer (score -1):

De acordo com o seu código, a variável "$row" não guarda o total de registros da consulta. Ele é um array criado durante a iteração dos resultados feita pelo foreach.

Você precisaria alterar o seu código para poder contar os resultados. Isso poderia ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC';
$pdo->prepare($sql);    
$pdo->execute();
$resultado = $pdo->fetchAll();
$total = count($resultado);
```

A variável "$resultado" vai ter um array com os resultados de sua consulta. A função "count" permite contar o número de elementos do array, que são o total de linhas retornadas pela consulta.

Desta forma, ou o conteúdo de "$total" é zero (a consulta não retornou registros) ou maior que zero (a consulta retornou registros). Desta forma, o seu código poderia ficar da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC';
$pdo->prepare($sql);    
$pdo->execute();
$resultado = $pdo->fetchAll();
$total = count($resultado);
foreach ($resultado as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['zname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['password'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=100%>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
if ($total >= 1){
    $sxURL="possui_registros.php";
    echo ("<script>location.href='$sxURL'</script>");
} else {
    $fxURL="nao_possui_registros.php";
    echo ("<script>location.href='$fxURL'</script>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

1º $sxURL = não é um camimho valido pois tem ESPAÇO.

2º se quiser fazer um redirect a melhor opção é essa:

```
header('Location: '.$sxURL);
exit();
```

OBS: lembra do protocolo se necessário.

Comment: Olá, A sintaxe parece estar correta porém aparece este erro:  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in `

Comment: Beleza ajustei encima do erro e deu certo `$q = $pdo->prepare($sql); $q->execute(array($id));
$resultado = $q->fetchAll();` a sintaxe está totalmente correta e deu certo, Obrigadão!!

Comment: **A função `header()` não vai funcionar!!!** Pra definir cabeçalhos na página é preciso que não haja nenhum html na saída. Ele ja exibiu uma `<table>`, então a função vai retornar `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`